# XPATH target the text nested <a> tag inside of a <p> tag

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to target text inside a

tag. There are some

tags that have nested  tags as well and my XPATH isn't targeting the text value of those  tags.

Link: https://help.lyft.com/hc/en-us/articles/115012925707-I-was-charged-incorrectly

Here is the XPATH I am using: `//article//p/text()`

Of course, I can `do //article//p//text()` and target the text but that also gets other links I don't want to extract. I only want to get all the text inside of a

tag and if there is any nested  tag, take that value too.

How can I achieve such a result?

[image]

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: I'm unsure of what you want to extract. You wrote *"I only want to get all the text inside of a tag and if there is any nested tag, take that value too"*, for that objective `//article//p/a//text()` would work, but I think that's not what you want. From your image, it seems you don't want the `a` tags that are by themselves, just the ones mingled in text, but you made no mention of it. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to select and what you don't want?

Answer (score 0):

As most of the pink-colored links start with **Learn**, I would probably go about it this way:

```
a = response.xpath('//article//p//a//text()').extract()
if "Learn" not in a and "Back to top" not in a:
    print(response.xpath('//article//p/text()').extract())
```